# Firebase - change a data field on closing the application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set a user's availability status (an isOnline boolean) in the Firebase Realtime Database precisely when the application is closed. This is something that I do in the `onDestroy` of my Service which gets called after a `stopService(myIntent)` in the activity.

This is how I am doing it in the onDestroy,

```
firebase.child("users").child(myUser.getUserName()).child("isOnline").setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
```

The problem is, this is never consistent even though the service `onDestroy` always gets called. Sometimes the `isOnline` flag would change and sometimes its just won't. Any ideas how I can get this right consistently ?